# What is the naming convention for AutoResetEvent objects?

Tags: c#, multithreading, naming-conventions

What is the naming convention for AutoResetEvents so that

1. A programmer intuitively knows that it is an AutoResetEvent
2. A programmer knows specifically what it is for

Say I have a method to refresh things which can only be called by one thread at a time

I find something like "resfreshThingAutoResetEvent" to be cumbersome, but it is the only way I can think to name it so that it meets the goals above.

Comment: `_dontTouchThisOrThingsBreak`

Comment: I used to name it `signal` or `jobSignal` etc. ummm it depends..

Comment: @MarcelN. +1 You're amusing man ;)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: All jokes aside, developer awareness is more important here than actual naming (which is not to be ignored, of course). Something with signal in it is usually fine.

Comment: FYI, years later, I've been going with "signal[TheThingThatItSignals]"